# How can I prove the equation?

Tags: analysis

> assume $(0,∞)^n=(0,∞)\times...\times(0,∞)$ ,$f:(0,∞)^n\to\Re$ is 
>   defined by
>   $f(x_1,...x_n):=\frac{1}{(x_1···x_n)}+x_1+...x_n.$

How can I prove the equation,
$f(x_1,...,x_n)\ge n+1$
for

> > every $x=(x_1,...x_n)\in [(n+1)^{-n},n+1]^n$,
> >     and for 
> >     every $x=(x_1,...,x_n)\in (0,∞)^n$?

Answer (score 1):

Apply AM-GM inequality $a_1+a_2+\cdots + a_{n+1} \ge (n+1)\sqrt[n+1]{a_1a_2\cdots a_{n+1}}$  to $a_1 = \dfrac{1}{x_1x_2\cdots x_n}, a_2 = x_1,...,a_k= x_{k-1}, a_{n+1}= x_n$, the answer follows.